# Suppress "BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at"

Tags: perl

I have a module which needs to do some checking in a BEGIN block. This prevents the user from seeing a useless message down the line (during compile phase, seen in second BEGIN here).

The problem is that if I die inside the BEGIN the message I throw gets buried behind 
`BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at`. However I prefer `die` to `exit 1` since it would then be trappable. Should I just use `exit 1` or is there something I can do to suppress this additional message?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

BEGIN {
  my $message = "Useful message, helping the user prevent Horrible Death";
  if ($ENV{AUTOMATED_TESTING}) {
    # prevent CPANtesters from filling my mailbox
    print $message;
    exit 0;
  } else {

    ## appends: BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at
    ## which obscures the useful message
    die $message;

    ## this mechanism means that the error is not trappable
    #print $message;
    #exit 1;

  }
}

BEGIN {
  die "Horrible Death with useless message.";
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you `die` you are throwing an exception that gets caught at an earlier call level.  The only handler that will catch the `die` from your `BEGIN` block is the compiler, and that is automatically attaching the error string you don't want.

To avoid this, you can either use the `exit 1` solution you found, or you can install a new die handler:

```
# place this at the top of the BEGIN block before you try to die

local $SIG{__DIE__} = sub {warn @_; exit 1};
```

Comment: Thanks! Now all I get is:
`Some needed modules are missing or must be upgraded before configuring Alien::GSL.
Those modules are: Sort::Versions`

Comment: I should say, which is what I wanted!